# Reloading DataTable after Data Save

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable, jquery-plugins

I need a quick suggestion where I am expecting the Datatable to be reloaded once the below Process.

1. DataTable is Initialized in A.php
2. Having a button in A.php to call a modal body from B.php
3. Data is Saved in B.php

I am trying to reload the data which has been entered in B.php from A.php. No solution seems like working. What am I missing?

**A.php**

```
//MODAL
<div class="modal effect-scale show" id="modBtn">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div id="add_mod"></div>
    </div>
</div>

//DATATABLE
$(document).ready(function{
    var table = ('#example').DataTable({
        //DataTable is Initialized
    });
});

//MODAL
$(document).on('click','#btnAdd',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#add').html('');
    var id=$(this).data('id');
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'b.php',
        data:{id:id},
        success : function(data)
        {
            $('#add').html('');
            $('#add').html(data);
            //NOT WORKING
            $('#example').DataTable().ajax.reload();
        }
    });
});
```

**B.php**

```
//MODAL CONTENT
<Modal Content>
    //CODE GOES HERE
</Modal Content>

//SAVE MODAL DATA
$("#form").on('submit', function(e){
    //CODE GOES HERE
}
```

How can I reload the DataTable once the modal data is saved? Where am I doing the mistake?

Comment: have you tried??? table.ajax.reload();

Comment: @KHIMAJIVALUKIYA yes, not working. its not about how the api is called. I think it is that where it is called.